# Why the Accordion in my react app is not working as I want it to be

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, css-grid, styled-components

I'm facing some issues with my React application.

**First I will explain what I want in my app then I will talk about the issues.**

I have a list of 6 Services and I want to wrap each service list in Accordion. Whenever the user clicks the "+" button for the specific service I want that list to be displayed with slides down with a growing margin-bottom, depending on the number of items in the respective list without overlapping the below element.

**While trying to achieve this, I'm facing the following issues.**

1- when I click "+" button it toggles all 6 services and their list items are getting displayed.

2- all list items overlapping the below elements.
[image]

**I tried with useState()**

```
const [showServices, setShowServices] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () =>{    
   setShowServices((prevState) => !prevState);
}

<div className="services__service__description">
  <h4 className="title">Services</h4>
  <span style={{cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: 'bold'}} id='showBtn' 
    onClick={toggle}>+</span>
  <div className="accordion">
    {text.map((t) => (                    
      <div className="content" id='services'>
         <div id='srvs' key={t.id}>
            {showServices ? t.info : ''}
         </div>
      </div>                                        
    ))}
   </div>
</div>
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mclean-4x5hvs?file=/src/Services.jsx)

Comment: please add a reproducible sample ... try codesandbox / stackblitz for making one, then write, save code and share link

Comment: thanks for your reply @KcH. I have added codesandbox link, kindly check the same.

Comment: Again I checked your codesandbox.
you are using single state for all Item
review my answer to understand what happend

Comment: @AliasgharAhmadpour, Yes I got it completely. I have to use another state, I check yours and KcH answers both are not addressing to my second question.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a separate state for the selected accordion like below

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

.... 

const toggle = (type) => {
    type === selected ? setShowServices(false) : setShowServices(true);
    setSelected(type);
  };
```

and check the condition while rendering as

```
<div id="srvs" key={t.id}>
      {showServices && selected === type ? t.info : ""}  // like so
</div>
```

Please check the below sandbox and fork it for your reference

- I'm not sure of styling to answer your other Q sorry

[image: Edit cool-estrela-hf7plv]

Comment: thank you @KcH, it resolves the first issue. But, it still overlaps the below elements. How can I wrap it in accordion and when open, push the below elements down. I want the height of each service to be dynamic which depends on the number of list items.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm poor at  .... you can probably open a new Q tagging `css` ...

Answer (score 0):

As I guss from part of your code, you binded single state to all Service related info.

The state `showServices` is shared between all item and when it changed from one item, then affect all other items.

Define new child component for info like example that i prepare for you.

```js
function ServiceDetail({ service }) {
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
    function toggle() {
        setShow(s => !s);
    }

 return   <div className="detail">
        <h4 className="title">{service.name}</h4>
        <span style={{ cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: '20px', fontWeight: 'bold' }} id='showBtn'
            onClick={toggle}>+</span>
        <div className="accordion">
            {service.detail.map((t, index) => (
                <div  key={index} className="content" id='services'>
                    <div id='srvs'>
                        {show ? t : ''}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
}

function Service() {
    const [services, setServices] = React.useState(
        [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Service 1",
                detail: ["list-1","list-2","list-3"]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Service 2",
                detail: ["bb"]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Service 3",
                detail: ["bb"]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Service 4",
                detail: ["bb"]
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: "Service 5",
                detail: ["bb"]
            }
        ]
    );
    return <div className="service">
        {
            services.map((service) => {
                return <ServiceDetail key={service.id} service={service} />
            })
        }
    </div>
}



function App() {
    return <Service />;
}

ReactDOM.render(< App className="app" />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.app{
width:100%;
}
.service{
display:grid;
column-gap: 1rem;
align-items:flex-start;
align-content:flex-start;
row-gap: 2rem;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.detail{
color:#9c772d;
background:#eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Edit: For size problem, just you need to add following css to container as i add to sample:

```
align-items:flex-start;
align-content:flex-start;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @Aliasghar. It will also overlap the below elements. How can I wrap it in accordion and when open, push the below elements down. I want the height of each service to be dynamic which depends on the number of list items.

Comment: Thank you @Aliasghar, I tried with the above 2 lines of CSS. It gives me all services in one line but my app layout is 3 & 3 as shown in the attached image.